# Java-8 addAll Objects

Tags: java, java-8

Is there a better way of doing this in Java 8?

```
final List<InstitutionUserConnection> allInstitutionUserConnections = new ArrayList<>();
for (final Institution institution : institutionsOfUser) {
    allInstitutionUserConnections
        .addAll(institutionUserConnectionService.getActiveInstitutionUserConnectionsByInstitution(institution));
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of flat mapping the inner list to a stream, you can also map it directly to a List, and then use a custom collector to append the element. The advantage of using a collector above using the stream, is that using a collector, you can get higher performance because the fact it uses 1 large `addAll` call, instead of separate small `add` calls like the `Collectors.toList()` does.

A solution based on this looks like:

```
List<InstitutionUserConnection> result = institutionsOfUser.stream().
        .map(institutionUserConnectionService::getActiveInstitutionUserConnectionsByInstitution)
        .collect(Collector.of(ArrayList::new, List::addAll,
                (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; }));
```

Comment: Reference to 'addAll' is ambiguous, both 'addAll(Collection<? extends E>)' and 'addAll(int, Collection<? extends E>)' match

Answer (score 11):

Yes, this is what the [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) operation is for:

```
List<InstitutionUserConnection> allInstitutionUserConnections =
    institutionsOfUser.stream()
                      .flatMap(institution -> institutionUserConnectionService.getActiveInstitutionUserConnectionsByInstitution(institution).stream())
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If the method throws a checked exception, then you need to catch it and handle it with logging, rethrowing an unchecked exception and/or returning a default value.

```
List<InstitutionUserConnection> allInstitutionUserConnections =
    institutionsOfUser.stream()
                      .flatMap(institution -> {
                          try {
                              return institutionUserConnectionService.getActiveInstitutionUserConnectionsByInstitution(institution).stream();
                          } catch (TheCheckedThrownException e) {
                              // do something here, like throw an unchecked exception
                          }
                      })
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: institutionUserConnectionService.getActiveInstitutionUserConnectionsByInstitution(institution) throws an Exception. Is there also a possibility to handle this? Thanks a lot!